# Antlr4 for Python: Parse data into parts

Tags: python, antlr4

I have a very simple grammar for Antlr4:

```
grammar settings;

query
    : COLUMN OPERATOR (SETTING|SCALAR)
    ;

COLUMN
    : [a-z_]+
    ;

OPERATOR
    : ('='|'>'|'<')
    ;

SETTING
    : 'setting(' [a-z_]+ ')'
    ;

SCALAR
    : [a-z_]+
    ;
```

I would like for input strings like `total_sales>setting(min_total_sales)` (they represent database column name, operator and value) define what is column name, operator, value. For that some python code was developed:

```
import re

from antlr4 import InputStream, CommonTokenStream

from settingsLexer import settingsLexer
from settingsParser import settingsParser

settings = {
    'min_total_sales': 1000
}

conditions = 'total_sales>setting(min_total_sales)'

lexer = settingsLexer(InputStream(conditions))
stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
parser = settingsParser(stream)
tree = parser.query()

regex = re.compile('^setting\((?P<setting_name>[a-z_]+)\)$')

column = None
operator = None
value = None

for child in tree.getChildren():
    text = child.getText()

    # how to match what is child: column or operator or value???

    # this for value defining
    if match := regex.match(text):
        setting_name = match.group('setting_name')
        print(f'We should get value from setting named `{setting_name}`')
        min_total_sales = settings['min_total_sales']
    else:
        print(f'We got a simple scalar value: {text}')
        min_total_sales = int(text)
```

How to match what is child: column name or operator or value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you involving regex? When you have parsed the input, the `tree` structure will contain methods that correspond to the rules it matched. So, the object returned by `parser.query()`, which is the parser rule:

```
query
    : COLUMN OPERATOR (SETTING|SCALAR)
    ;
```

will have 4 methods: `COLUMN()`, `OPERATOR()`, `SETTING()` and `SCALAR()`

Use them to extract the data you want:

```py
tree = parser.query()

column = tree.COLUMN()
operator = tree.OPERATOR()
setting = tree.SETTING()

print(f"column={column}, operator={operator}, setting={setting}")
```

And I'd not glue the `setting` and `min_total_sales` into 1 big token, but let this be done by the parser instead. Otherwise input like `total_sales>setting ( min_total_sales )` will not be matched because of the spaces.

```
grammar settings;

query
    : COLUMN OPERATOR value EOF
    ;

value
    : setting
    | SCALAR
    ;

setting
    : SETTING '(' SCALAR ')'
    ;

COLUMN
    : [a-z_]+
    ;

OPERATOR
    : ('='|'>'|'<')
    ;

SETTING
    : 'setting'
    ;

SCALAR
    : [a-z_]+
    ;

SPACES
    : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
    ;
```

Comment: Oh, thanx very much.
Could you say please whether that worked for you? I'm getting error (Python 3): mismatched input 'setting' expecting {'setting', SCALAR}. I tried different inputs: "total_sales>setting(min_total_sales)", "total_sales>val", etc. The error message all the same

Comment: The  code snippet I posted works with your grammar. The code will not work with my suggested grammar changes.